# Adding rel="next" and rel="prev" with paginate_links() function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, seo

Inside my archive template, I'm using a pagination.
it is generated by the function `paginate_links()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/

I try to find out how to implement rel attributes : **next and prev** inside the links, like this :

`<a class="page-numbers" rel="prev" href="mywebsite.fr/blog/page/1/#target">1</a>`

`<span class="page-numbers current" href="mywebsite.fr/blog/page/2/#target">2</span>`

`<a class="page-numbers" rel="next" href="mywebsite.fr/blog/page/3/#target">3</a>`

Have you ever encountered this problem ? Have you use a hook ?

Thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 1):

You can add `rel=prev` and `rel=next` to your paginated links by adding the `prev_text` and `next_text` arguments like the following:

```
paginate_links(array(
        'prev_text'    => __('previous'),
        'next_text'    => __('next'),
    ));
```

Comment: This only add previous / next text as string inside of link. The question is how to add ``rel`` param.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I took the HTML template returned by the function and replaced the string near the class of link, like this:

```
{{ paginationHTML|replace({'class="prev' : 'rel="prev" class="prev', 'class="next' : 'rel="next" class="next'}) }}
```

In my case I'm using twig, but you can easily change that to PHP replace.

Answer (score 0):

While [Google doesn't need them](https://yoast.com/google-doesnt-use-rel-prev-next-for-pagination/), and it is better to do nothing then it incorrectly, here is a way using the `paginate_links_output` filter to add the'rel="next"' and 'rel="prev"' attribute to the next and previous links in the paginate_links function in WordPress.

https://gist.github.com/TimBHowe/1604b163230337a5d3a312f8e1c7599b

```
<?php
/**
 * Alter the pagination next and prev links to have rel.
 *
 * @param string $r    HTML output.
 * @param array  $args An array of arguments. See paginate_links() for information on accepted arguments.
 *
 * @return sting - The HTML output of the pagination.
 */
function scaffolding_add_rel_pagination( $r, $args ) {

    $r = str_replace( 'class="prev', 'rel="prev" class="prev', $r );
    $r = str_replace( 'class="next', 'rel="next" class="next', $r );

    return $r;
}
add_filter( 'paginate_links_output', 'scaffolding_add_rel_pagination', 20, 2 );
```